# Find length of an item in a list [Python]

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops

I've searched and searched and can't find anything to help. I have a list that goes like this

```
['EGLC', 'LON', 'TUPIN', 'WEEE', 'KJFK']
```

The first and last items are ignored, but i need to find the length of each item in between. The list has no set size or format, so they length change. I need to find the length of the second item (LON) (The length will be either 3 or 5), then i run it through something, and then it must loop back and check the length of the second item, and repeat, but NOT check the length of the last one.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The length of the three items in between can be found using this:

```
mylist = ['EGLC', 'LON', 'TUPIN', 'WEEE', 'KJFK']
lengths = [len(i) for i in mylist[1:-1]]
print(lengths)
```

The output is:

```
[3, 5, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use list comprehension to get the length of all the elements except the first and the last one:

```
my_list = ['EGLC', 'LON', 'TUPIN', 'WEEE', 'KJFK']

len_list = [len(x) for x in my_list[1:-1]]
```

Check this link for more such examples : [List comprehensions in Python](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python)

Here is the [Official Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Comment: That one gave me an Unexpected EOF while parsing :/

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
a = ['EGLC', 'LON', 'TUPIN', 'WEEE', 'KJFK']
[len(a[item_]) for item_ in range(1, len(a)-1)]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this simplest way, like :

```
arr = ['EGLC', 'LON', 'TUPIN', 'WEEE', 'KJFK']
length = []
for i in range(1, len(arr) - 1):
  length.append(len(arr[i]))

print(length)
```

**Or,** Apply another process :

```
arr = ['EGLC', 'LON', 'TUPIN', 'WEEE', 'KJFK']
length = []
for val in arr[1:-1]:
  length.append(len(val))

print(length)
```

Output :

```
[3, 5, 4]
```

Comment: That's brilliant, thanks! :) Anyway to make it print [3, 4, 5] instead of [3] [3, 4] [3, 4, 5,]? (EDIT, worked it out)

Comment: Yes, It prints `[3, 4, 5]`. If you write `print(length, end=" ")` into the `for` loop, then output will be `[3] [3, 5] [3, 5, 4] `.